# How to clean up SVG imported Splines?

Tags: vector

I'm not the most computer literate person but I have been improving substantially since I got a 3d printer. So I am trying to print an image a friend sent me from a t-shirt. I converted it to an svg and loaded into blender, I have done this before and just deleted all the wobbly points manually and replaced any crazy looking text myself but this is a ton of work is there an easier way to take all this wonky crap out and just get smooth lines?

In the attached image (if I did even attach it correctly) the smooth curve on the right I manually corrected and all the crap on the left is still probably another hour worth of junk to fix.

If there is some video or this has been asked and answered a million times my apologies but I dont even really know what question to ask since I dont understand 90% of the terms used in Blender anyways.

[image]

Comment: You may want to start with an intro to modelling in blender course.  But here's one for some of your issues.
https://youtu.be/gt-E2kPs2hY?feature=shared